# Randomly change logo when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollspy

I have a site with fullheight sections using fullpage.js. Every section has a unique class of ".row" and classes ".light" or ".dark", depending on the row.

I'm trying to change between 6 dark & light svg logos randomly on every scroll.

Every logo has a unique name like so:

```
dark_logo_1.svg
dark_logo_2.svg
dark_logo_3.svg
...
light_logo_1.svg
light_logo_2.svg
light_logo_3.svg
...
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a id="logo" href="#">
    <img id="moody-logo" src="">
  </a>
</nav>

<body>
 <div class="row light">CONTENT</div>
 <div class="row dark">CONTENT</div>
 <div class="row light">CONTENT</div>
 <div class="row dark">CONTENT</div>
...
</body>
```

This is my jquery code so far, using scrollspy.js:

```
<script src="http://path-to-js-folder/scrollspy.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

$('.row').on('scrollSpy:exit', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('dark')){
        var newColor = "light";
    } else {
        var newColor = "dark";
    }

   var logoFileName = newColor + "_logo_" + randomNumber + ".svg";

    $("#moody-logo").attr("src", "http://path-to-logos-folder/" + logoFileName);
});
});
```

Kinda stuck, can't get the src in html for my #moody-logo to show anything other than blank src (src="").

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the src in html showing (unknown)?

Comment: When I inspect the logo element, src is empty, like so> src=""

Comment: When you open your dev tools, are there any errors? My guess is that your event "scrollSpy:exit" is not firing at all. I'm not too familiar with scrollspy.js, but I don't see it being used like you're using it. Maybe try jquery-scrollspy: https://github.com/softwarespot/jquery-scrollspy?